# How to make Sonar Scanner (Runner) find objc plugin

Tags: objective-c, sonarqube

Currently, I'm setting up Sonarqube for objective-c project.
SonarQube : 5.4 (worked)
Sonar runner: 2.8
Sonar Plugin for Objective C : https://github.com/octo-technology/sonar-objective-c

but when I try to run sonar runner for the project then terminal said:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: You must install a plugin that supports the language 'objc'
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
ERROR - Command 'sonar-runner ' failed with error code: 1
```

Could you please give me some advice ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237547/sonarqube-typescript-plugin-you-must-install-a-plugin-that-supports-the-langua Almost the same, except that you need to write "objc" instead of "ts" ?

Comment: I set objc already !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of SonarQube you are using but for SonarQube version 6.7(Latest), you can download Objective-C plugin from [here](https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-objective-c/releases/download/0.6.2/backelite-sonar-objective-c-plugin-0.6.2.jar) and copy it to :

> SONAR_HOME/extensions/plugins/

In my case it was `/usr/local/Cellar/sonarqube/6.7.1/libexec/extensions/plugins/`

Restart the SonarQube server and you're good to go.

It's an old issue but I hope this helps someone.